# Display all values on X-axis android studio

Tags: java, android, android-graphview

I have implemented a line graph using graphview in my app that allows the user to input data daily and records it by the date, but I am having an issue to display all the values on the x-axis.
I used this line of to separate the blocks `weightGraph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(5);` and then looks like the image below where the values are overlapping each other. [image]

and if I change the value of 5 to 3 in this code`weightGraph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(3);` then it does not display all the values like the picture below.

[image]

Is there any other way to display it so all the x-axis values are visible, with it overlapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show vertical (or at least at an angle) using `.setHorizontalLabelsAngle(90);`

Comment: This works but still if I exceed 5 days then my data will not display

Comment: In this case, you can change your graph dimension, or your string dimension.

Comment: I currently have it in a linearlayout and the graph is set to match parent any advice on what should change it to

Comment: try `getGraphViewStyle().setTextSize(5);`

Comment: I guess it will help you, XAxis xAxis=chart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(-45);

Comment: Is there any way to make values increase by 1 instead of it by 2 currently . Eg : 29/09/2020 to 01/10/2020 instead of being 29/09/2020 to 02/10/2020

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to remove this line of code `weightGraph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(10);`
Which enables the graph to increase as it wants daily but I did add this line of code so the x values do not overlap each other. `weightGraph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHorizontalLabelsAngle(45);`